# WebSphere Portal serve 8 theme issue

Tags: themes, websphere-portal

creating a theme for WAS Portal server 8.1 that's working fine on test server but and deployed on production server its module not load css and js files but when we run server as debug mode that's load all css and js but in normal mode it can not load css and js file

Comment: It is hard to help out based on what you have provided. In what way does it not load the css and js files? Do you get any error messages? Are you uncluding them as resources in the jsp files or are you including them inline? Do you have any code where you reference the files?

Comment: i found solution i validate all css and js file and its working...